# Background image on JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, background

I begin in the Java programming language. I would like to make a JFrame and put a background image on it and above the JFrame, I would like to insert widgets : JTextArea , JButton ... but they can not overlap. Here is my code :

```
public void go() {
    cadre = new JFrame("Premiere Feneêtre");
    cadre.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cadre.setSize(600, 600);
    cadre.setVisible(true);`

    BorderLayout agencement = new BorderLayout();
    JPanel arrierePlan = new JPanel(agencement);
    arrierePlan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    Box boiteABoutons = new Box(BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
    boiteABoutons.setSize(150,150);
    boiteABoutons.setOpaque(false);
    //boiteABoutons.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    b1 = new JButton("Bouton 1");
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2 = new JButton("Bouton 2");
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3 = new JButton("Bouton 3");
    boiteABoutons.add(b1);
    boiteABoutons.add(b2);
    boiteABoutons.add(b3);
    zoneTexte = new JTextArea();

    Panneau p1 = new Panneau();
    arrierePlan.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, boiteABoutons);
    arrierePlan.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,zoneTexte);

    cadre.getContentPane().add(p1);
    cadre.getContentPane().add(arrierePlan);

}

public class Panneau extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        try {
            Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/........png"));
            //g.drawImage(img, 10, 10, this);
            g.drawImage(img, 10, 10, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've read several things here regarding this problem I encounter, but nothing really helped me .

Thank you
Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cadre.getContentPane().add(p1);
cadre.getContentPane().add(arrierePlan);
```

You can't add multiple component to the CENTER of a BorderLayout.

Instead you want to add the component to the image panel:

```
Panneau p1 = new Panneau();
p1.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
p1.add(boiteABoutons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
p1.add(zoneTexte, BorderLayout.NORTH);
cadre.add(p1);
```

In the future search the forum before asking a question (the topic title usually contains good keywords to start with). As you can see by the posting found under the `Related` heading on the right side of this page, this question is asked frequently.